# Play framework anorm: method xx is defined twice

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm currently writing a webapp with the Play Framework 2.1.

When I go to http://xyz.com/packages I want an overview screen of all sites to be displayed.

When I go to http://xyz.com/packages/34 I want an detail screen of the item with id=34.

I have configured the routes file like this:

```
GET     /items                  controllers.Application.items
GET     /items/:id              controllers.Application.items(id: Long)
```

Now I get the error:

```
method items is defined twice conflicting symbols both originated in file 
    ... routes_reverseRouting.scala
```

How can I resolve this?
Thanks!

Comment: The compiler never lies... Just rename one of the two methods.

Answer (score 0):

Changing it to this worked. Still it would have been interesting to know why it did not work...

```
GET     /items                  controllers.Application.itemsAll
GET     /items/:id              controllers.Application.items(id: Long)
```

Comment: Because two routes cannot map to the same method. You can however bind them with a fixed value, check out my [tutorial](http://www.mariussoutier.com/blog/2012/12/10/playframework-routes-part-1-basics/).